# Is there a way to input values on a CSS file from a Form Field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

For example,
I would like to have a form field that says 'Background Color' and when I input a HEX color on the field, it knows to place the value under the background-color: [value from form];

I'm having difficulties finding articles on this on the web so any help is well appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`stylesheet.insertRule()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmpkap.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe take a look at using a function that runs on blur like below. So in the form you would need to enter #000 or similar and then when you click out of the field the background colour will change.

```
<form action="#">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter hex">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('form input').on('blur', function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', $(this).val());
        });
 });
</script>
```